# What does the final shot mean in the Unholy?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-unholy

In the movie, the Unholy, there are a few occasions where the sculptures of Jesus and Virgin Mary cry blood from their eyes. From what I can recall, most of them make sense:

- When Alice calls out the demon as Virgin Mary, inside of the church, Virgin Mary cries blood from her eyes; which indicates Alice is worshipping a false idol.
- When the cross inside of the church is lit on fire and crashes a priest and killing him, Jesus cries blood from his eyes; which indicates the tragic end for a devoted priest.
- After the demon has been banished, Alice becomes hearing-impaired again, everything returns to peace; just before the end of this movie, we see Virgin Mary cries blood from her eyes again. Why? As I cannot see any indication of the banished demon will return or Alice has been possessed by the demon.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://cooncel.com/the-unholy-ending-explained-spoiler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my theory. Because Mary lived through her own bloodline and Alice is the only descendant of Mary, when Alice died Mary was also killed. And that should have been the end of it. BUT because Fenn prayed to God to bring Alice back, this meant Mary once again had a link to the living world, and thus we see the statue crying blood again. (Although at this point, Alice is no longer possessed.) That's the twist at the end of the movie.